# Rebus SqlServerTransport, "MissingIndex" from SQL Server seems incorrect, or something isn't working as intended

Tags: sql-server, rebus

SQL Server is reporting that the Messages table used by `Rebus` and it's `SQLServerTransport` are needing a different index created for it.  I feel the current index setup is correct, but something about the usage of a CTE, deleting, and outputting is causing SQL Server to do something.

Is SQL Server wrong on the index or is the CTE doing something unexpected here?

SQL Server is requesting and index along the lines of

```
CREATE INDEX IX_<NewNameHere> 
ON [MessageQueues].[dbo].[Messages] ([id]) 
INCLUDE ([recipient], [priority])
```

where are currently the clustered index is like

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [recipient] ASC,
    [priority] ASC,
    [id] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and here is the only query being ran against this DB.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON

;WITH TopCTE AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        [id], [headers], [body]
    FROM
        [Messages] M WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    WHERE    
        M.[recipient] = @recipient
        AND M.[visible] < getdate()
        AND M.[expiration] > getdate()
    ORDER BY        
        [priority] ASC, [id] ASC
)
DELETE FROM TopCTE
OUTPUT deleted.[id] as [id],
       deleted.[headers] as [headers],
       deleted.[body] as [body]
', N'@recipient nvarchar(200)', @recipient=N'Location'
```

Update:
I was wrong on the query that was causing the wanted index.  Rebus does a periodic message `PerformExpiredMessagesCleanupCycle` which runs this query

```
DELETE FROM [{_tableName}] 
    WHERE [id] IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 [id] FROM [{_tableName}] WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
            WHERE [recipient] = @recipient 
                AND [expiration] < getdate()
    )

```

is where the wanted index is coming from.

Comment: Some additional info, SQL Server 2008R2, no service packs.

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2 does NOT seem to be related to this as the missing index is showing up in 2016 and 2008R2sp1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebus, for each queue, does a periodic clean up to delete all expired messages.  It did this

    `command.CommandText =$@"
        DELETE FROM [{_tableName}] 
        WHERE [id] IN (
            AND [expiration] < getdate()
        )
";`

If the query was like this

    `command.CommandText =$@"
            ;with TopCTE as (
                SELECT TOP 1 [id] FROM [{_tableName}] WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
                WHERE [recipient] = @recipient 
                AND [expiration] < getdate()
            )
            DELETE FROM TopCTE
    ";`

then there wouldn't be a need to do the secondary lookup which is causing the `ID` column to be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "SQL Server is reporting that (...) needing a different index"? Where do you see that?

I am not an expert on SQL Server.... but when I get the actual query plan from executing the query on a table with the index that Rebus automatically creates, I get this plan:

[image: query plan]

Now, since I am not an expert, there is probably a lot that I am missing when I look at these things. But I do know that the thing to watch out for, is "index scan", whereas "index seek" is good because it means that SQL Server is actually using an index.

---

In order to check whether the index suggested by SQL Server would have an impact, I conducted a test where I measure the time it takes an endpoint to receive 10000 messages.

In the first round, the test runs with the usual configuration - i.e. *without* the index suggested by SQL Server:

```
10000 messages received in 12,5 s - that's 801,5 msg/s
```

In the second round, I add the index suggested by SQL Server:

```
10000 messages received in 13,6 s - that's 736,2 msg/s
```

And in this third round I add the index suggested by SQL Server AND drop the index which Rebus creates by itself:

```
10000 messages received in 13,8 s - that's 722,6 msg/s
```

Here are the results summed up in a neat little ASCII table:

```
+---------------+-----------+----------------------+
| Current index | New index | Approx. receive rate |
+---------------+-----------+----------------------+
|      Yes      |    No     |      800 msg/s       |
|      Yes      |    Yes    |      735 msg/s       |
|      No       |    Yes    |      720 msg/s       |
+---------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

From this – granted, not very thorough, but probably indicative enough – test, it seems that it does not improve the receive rate if the index suggested by SQL Server is used.

Comment: I use this query to get "Missing Indexes" reported by SQL Server.

https://gist.github.com/xenoputtss/c185d02b5797cc9b25101e42d9cd04b2

Comment: I updated the answer with results after running a test with the suggested index

Comment: Your results is what I would expect by looking at the query and the primary index.  What version of sql server are you running this against?  I'm thinking at this point that perhaps this is an issue with the particular version of SQL Server we are running.

Comment: 2016..... and I actually got the same suggestion when I ran the query from your gist...

Comment: I generated much more data in my test environment and I am now getting the "Missing Index" there too.  I'm looking a little more into this still.

Comment: I figured it out.  Had noting to do with the standard "pop" next message logic.  I'll post an answer with my results, and get a pull request over to you with the fix.